# How do I insert an entry into browsing history via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, back-button, back-button-control

How do I insert an entry into browsing history so back button goes to different page 1st click then original page on 2nd click?

So if you need a good explanation of what I want done, go to:
https://secure.exitjunction.com/howitworks.jsp

I just need a script that will allow me to insert an entry in the browsing history so when back button is hit, the user will be taken to my special page.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a jQuery Plugin:

[jQuery Plugin](http://github.com/christianhellsten/jquery-google-analytics/tree/master)

Comment: there are plenty of answers on google for this. I recommended an option that uses jquery but there are straight javascript options for this.

Comment: This is the best plugin by far to work with history, and I've worked with a number of them including a couple of standalone libraries. Even YUI's history object has some bugs in it. This one is the best of them.

Comment: I should also note, even if you were to "write your own", I would use this one as the reference implementation.

Comment: again - use this to get an idea for the code since you are not interested in adding google analytics support

Comment: Thanks NTulip and altCognito - this gives me a basis to work from.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly manipulate the browsing history.

Such a feature would be seen as a security hole (and it would be), so I doubt that any browsers would ever implement it.

You might be able to hack around it however by doing something like this:

NOTE: This entirely hinges around the assumption that the referrer will get changed by the back button. I don't think this actually happens, so it more than likely won't work, but hey.

You have two pages, PageA and PageB.

- The user hits PageA
- The page (on the client, using javascript) checks the HTTP referrer, and if it is not PageB, then it immediately redirects the user to PageB.
- Now that you're on PageB, if the user clicks the back button, it will go back to PageA.
- PageA will check the referrer, it <s>will</s>may be PageB, so there is no redirect.

Comment: i thought that's what he was looking for.he is looking to track exit links