# Need temporary Client-side solution for handling browser "Back" button

Tags: asp.net, javascript, caching, client-side

At this moment I cannot make changes to the code behind for a few weeks, but can change the .aspx file.

We have some **internal** users that will click the IE7 "back" button to navigate back 5 or 6 pages (which is specifically against stated rules and training).  There are a very few pages where this is causing us major problems with duplicating transactions because the buttons that should be disabled, were enabled in past pages.  I am trying the OutputCache directive which causes the user to see that the "page has expired", but I anticipate that they will then click the "refresh" button, and then presents the same problem.

As I said this is a temporary fix until I can modify the code-behind in a few weeks.

Instead of getting the "page has expired", can I have it go to a different .aspx using javascript?  Basically, I'll be sending them to the page at the level above, where they can then pick this page and enter it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, obviously not your fault, but in reference to "specifically against the stated rules in training," have to link here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/news/fog0000000322.html

Comment: I agree.  This happens to be on a page with legacy code.  Otherwise, we would have programmed for this.  All current code handles this correctly.  The reason I'm tasked with fixing this quickly is that we don't want to interrupt the current users, just save them from this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

It will take a bit of work in modifying your client side logic, but overall it should be worth it until you can fix things at a higher level.

Comment: Using this one, but still having problems.  Once they are better defined, I'll create new jquery question.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change which page the back button navigates to by inserting an entry into the browsing history - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754248/how-do-i-insert-an-entry-into-browsing-history-via-javascript) for details about some different approaches.